# sed gives unknown command error: char 1: unknown command: `''

Tags: python-3.x, sed

i am trying to use `sed` to do some text processing  in a file called `host`

```
cluster_ip = "10.223.10.21"
srv_domain = "service_domain.svc"
cmd = f"'/^.*{srv_domain}/!p;$a'{cluster_ip}'\t{srv_domain}'"
```

Then I am calling it  like this

```
subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/sed", "-i", "-ne", cmd,  "host"])
```

But i am getting this error:

```
/usr/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

Could someone please explain me what am I doing wrong?
Thank You

I also tried using `fileinput` but i am unable to print `print(f"{cluster_ip}\t{srv_domain}\n")` to the file instead this is going to the console.

```
cluster_ip = "123.234.45.5"
srv_domain = "service_domain.svc"
def main():
    pattern = '^.*service_domain.svc'
    filename = "host1"
    matched = re.compile(pattern).search
    with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=1) as file:
        for line in file:
            if not matched(line): # save lines that do not match
                print(line, end='') # this goes to filename due to inplace=1
        # this is getting printed in console 
        print(f"{cluster_ip}\t{srv_domain}\n")

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to remove the first line and add a last line. You don't need to protect arguments, it's already done by the `subprocess` module. so you're getting the quotes literally.

quickfix:

```
cmd = f"/^.*{srv_domain}/!p;$a{cluster_ip}\t{srv_domain}"
```

better: learn to use python to avoid calling `sed` in your script and make them complex and non portable.  You don't even need regexes here, just substring search (which could be improved with regexes to avoid substring match but the problem is already present in the original expression)

First read your file, drop the line where srv_domain is defined, and add your last line.

Something like this, using a temporary file to hold the modified contents, then overwriting it:

```
with open("hosts") as fr,open("hosts2","w") as fw:
    for line in fr:
        if not srv_domain in line:
            fw.write(line)
    fw.write(f"{cluster_ip}\t{srv_domain}\n")

os.remove("hosts")
os.rename("hosts2","hosts")
```

Comment: i was also trying to use python to do this using `fileinput`  module. instead of writing the file, it is writing to the console.

which one is better between the two python solutions?